# Using Tomcat connection pool in JBoss AS 5.x

Tags: tomcat, jdbc, jboss, jndi

How can I create ConnectionPool/JDBC in JBoss without change any code in my application? I already have the deploy file (.WAR).

For example, in tomcat I just needed to add a new resource to the server.xml file. Something like that:

```
...
<GlobalNamingResources>
    ...
    <Resource driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" name="testDBConnectionPool" password="root" type="javax.sql.DataSource" url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/testDB" username="root"/>
    ...
</GlobalNamingResources>
...
```

How to do it in JBoss? As I can understand, JBoss uses [mysql-ds.xml file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/820116/jboss-database-connection-pool) for that but we need to call it in the code. Am I right?

Is there any similar approach like Tomcat in JBoss?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add required info in mysql-ds.xml and put it in  $JBOSS_HOME/dirserver/default/deploy .

If your datasource name is jdbc/MySQLDS , then you can call it like

```
javax.naming.Context ic = new javax.naming.InitialContext();
javax.naming.Context ctx = (javax.naming.Context) ic.lookup("java:");
javax.sql.DataSource ds = (javax.sql.DataSource) ctx.lookup("jdbc/MySQLDS");
java.sql.Connection con = ds.getConnection();
```

update:

you need to make sure mysql-ds.xml has the exact values which are there in server.xml of tomcat.

Comment: Thanks, but my problem is that I can't change the code. I just have the WAR file to publish...
The jdbc connection is defined inside the WAR in the persistence.xml.

Comment: You don't have to change anything just configure the data source and post. You would refer with JDBC datasource given inside context.xml or web.xml file. As long as your name's are not different in context.xml/web.xml vs *-ds.xml in JBoss. They all should work.